# How to create new instances of classes based on a CSV file

Tags: java, class, csv, instantiation

Let's say I have a class, Car, and I'm trying to import a large set of data to create multiple instances of "Car".

My CSV file is laid out like so:

Car Manufacturer,Model,Color,Owner,MPG,License Plate,Country of Origin,VIN,... etc

The point is, there is a lot of data that needs to be in the constructor. If there's only a few of these, it wouldn't be that bad to manually instantiate it by writing `Car FordFocus = new Car(Ford,Focus,Blue,John Doe,108-J1AZ,USA,194241-12e1...)`, but if I have hundreds of these, is there any way to import all this data to make the classes?

Comment: I'm voting to close as you need a tool for this, and SO is not for asking for tool recommendations.  Google for "Java CSV" and you should find some tools on your own.  Try them out and if you have problems coding, post your specific problems.

Comment: A tool? Do you mean a library? I tried Google as well as SO before I posted and couldn't find anything. Could you provide a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34806/george-jempty) mentions, you need a tool. I have used [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) before to achieve this.

opencsv provides you three mapping strategies (which can be further extended) for mapping a CSV row to bean. The simplest is ColumnPositionMappingStrategy. So if your CSV format is fixed, e.g. the header row looks like:

Car Manufacturer,Model,Color,Owner,MPG,License Plate,Country of Origin,VIN,... etc

This code snippet will help you. I have also used HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy which lets you map CSV header names to bean field names e.g. "Car Manufacturer" -> carManufacturer.

```
  CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
  ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<Car> strategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<Car>();
  strategy.setType(Car.class);
  String[] columns = new String[] {"CarManufacturer","Model","Color","Owner","MPG","LicensePlate","CountryOfOrigin","VIN"}; // the fields to bind do in your JavaBean
  strategy.setColumnMapping(columns);

  CsvToBean<Car> csv = new CsvToBean<Car>();
  List<Car> list = csv.parse(strategy, csvReader);
```

A self contained sample program can be found [here](https://github.com/vsnyc/soutils/blob/master/codepuzzles/src/main/java/com/vs/soutils/OpenCSVTest.java)

Comment: Okay, I think I'm beginning to understand. Let's say there's another column in the csv that defines the class name. Let's say there's a class called `fordFocus`. Does the `list` variable contain all these classes? How do I interact with `fordFocus` now?

Comment: Your class will be called Car and will have fields like String CarManufacturer, String Model, String Color, String Owner, and so on. The CSV file will contain the data, 1 row per Car, e.g. Ford, Focus, Red, John Doe... You will pass this CSV file to CSVReader. Later, when you do csv.parse(strategy, csvReader) - you will get a list of Car objects

Comment: So you access them using indices? Like if I wanted the "model" field of fordFocus, I couldn't call fordFocus.model; I would call list[3].model, if it was the fourth in the list? Thanks!

Comment: It would be `list.get(3).getModel()`. Typically you'd want a public getter method and keep the field `model` private.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is a possibility.
You can associate an attribute with a position in your CSV file (a column).

See for example of setting attribute with reflection : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html

Comment: Stating that reflection, or anything else for that matter "is a possibility" is hardly an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this works. Can you give me an example?

Comment: I disagree with @GeorgeJempty. Stating that reflection is a possibility is a valid answer; as the OP most likely never considered it. Additionally, Thierry explained briefly how to use reflection to achieve this and provided a link to a Java tutorial. There is sufficient information for the OP to investigate.  That said, IMHO, reflection would be my last choice; especially when there are tools that could do this way faster than using reflection.

Comment: @hfontanez When I made my comment the answer consisted of the first line only and not the link to the tutorial.  In any case you agree it's a bad option, plus the answer did not (and still does not) show how to use reflection in this specific use case.  Merely stating (fill in the blank) is a possibility is in my opinion always a poor quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the csv file line by line and can create the Car object by constructor in loop.

Comment: How will I be able to access the FordFocus object after? Can you give me an example?